# secure-http flag in a composer.json doesn't work

Tags: composer-php

I need to use http composer registry for several packages:

```
...
"repositories":[
  {"type":"composer", "url":"http://<url>"}
],
"secure-http":false,
...
```

But when I am trying to `composer update` to update lock file, I got:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
Your configuration does not allow connection to http://<url>.
See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
```

By responding url I found next information;

```
secure-http#

Defaults to true. 
If set to true only HTTPS URLs are allowed to be downloaded via Composer. 
If you really absolutely need HTTP access to something then you can disable it ...
```

So I am confused what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like I had some strcture composer.json problem. I'll try to find it out.

Comment: Yes, I am just stupid. Option `secure-http` as it told in the composer documentation must be in the `config` property.

Comment: Why didn't you accept your own the answer if it's the one that worked?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Wrong `composer.json` structure. `secure-http` must be in the `config` section:

```
{
  ...,
  "config":{
    ...,
    "secure-http":false,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Definitely deserves to be accepted at this point, can confirm still working Jan 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you could make it a global thorough writing :

```
composer config -g secure-http false
```