# configuration does not allow connection to http://packagist.org/packages.json

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, frameworks, composer-php

I am trying to install laravel in my computer.

I am refering to [turorails point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_installation.htm) laravel installation tutorial.

After installing composer trying to create new larael project but getting this error.

This is the error which I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting a link to an image, please [edit] your question and paste the error text directly into your question. Have you visited [the URL](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http) that Composer recommended?

Comment: Add "secure-http":false to "config" node in composer.json [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151172/secure-http-flag-in-a-composer-json-doesnt-work/36152835#36152835)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable OpenSSL in your Windows.

You can enable it from your `php.ini` file:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: Actually, I have installed wamp,xampp and php explicit also. I was giving main php.exe path instead of wamp server php.exe path for composer. I got it.

Answer (score 15):

I have the same issue, but then I try this:

```
composer config -g secure-http false
```

then I run again my Laravel, and it works.

Comment: At least in localhost, you can use this. Not recommended in production.

Answer (score 6):

```
Step 1: Set disable-tls = true
php composer.phar config -g disable-tls true
Step 2: Set secure-http = false
php composer.phar config -g secure-http false
```

The reason is: the url of the installation module is not https, reference manual:[https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#disable-tls](http://Https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#disable-tls)

Answer (score 3):

It works for me, try the step below :

*1 First clear the cached*

> composer clear-cache

*2 You have 2 options here:*

1. enable **OpenSSL** in your php.ini :

   > extension=php_openssl.dll
2. disable **TLS SSL** option for composer :

   > composer config -g -- disable-tls true

*3 Run again your **laravel** project :*

> composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist

Hope those steps can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Though the topic is pretty old atm, I just ram right into the problem, trying to install an extension using `composer` for my magento2 application with a network behind the `corp`. I found the solution myself after combining all of the suggestions I found lately, so here is it. The main task is pretty simple, use `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS` for `repo.packagist`, but we need some configuration in order to make it actually work.

```
composer clear-cache

composer config -g -- disable-tls true
composer config -g secure-http false
composer config -g repo.packagist composer http://repo.packagist.org

composer require "cadence/heimdall"
```